# How to check input values present in array or not using inArray in Jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, if-statement

I have array like below.

```
var myArray = [];
myArray = [70, 68, 64, 29, 1, 44, 39, 31, 26];
```

I need to check if any given number is in above array or not

Comment: I think a simple search would give you the answer

Answer (score 3):

You can use `.indexOf()` for that

```
if(myArray.indexOf(number) > -1){
    alert(number+" exists !!!");
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/B4ybw/)**

**Using Jquery**

```
 if($.inArray(number, myArray)>-1){
       alert(number+" exists !!!");
 }
```

**[Demo using inArray()](http://jsfiddle.net/R8jqD/)**

Comment: I think the question is specifically mentioned as inArray jQuery ?

Answer (score 1):

-------1.---------

```
for(var i=0; i<myArray.length; i++) {
   if(number==myArray[i]) {
       //process
       break;
   }
 }
```

-------2.---------

```
if(myArray.indexOf(number) > -1) {
      //process
}
```